# How to grab a new line in Word by Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have code that takes the contents of a Word file into a variable, so I parse the contents and handle it by VBA code.
My question is: I'm currently scanning letters by a loop, but I don't know how to find a line break.
Any help is appreciated
Thank you
This is the code I'm currently using

```
Sub open_word_find_text()

Dim book1 As Word.Application
Dim sheet1 As Word.Document
Set book1 = CreateObject("word.application")
book1.Visible = True

                GetFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename   'Select a file'
                         Filename = Mid(GetFilePath, InStrRev(GetFilePath, "\") + 1, 999):
                        FilePath = Mid(GetFilePath, 1, InStrRev(GetFilePath, Filename) - 2)
 find_text = InputBox("Type the text you are looking for:")
     
file = Dir(FilePath & "\")

               While (file <> "")  'loop over all the files in the folder
                  
                  If InStr(file, ".docx") > 0 Then
              
                      Filename = Mid(file, InStrRev(file, "\") + 1, 999):
                      
                       Set sheet1 = book1.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & file)
                                                             
                            ff = sheet1.Content   'Save the contents of the file in a variable
                                  count_result = 0
                             For i = 1 To Len(ff)

                                  ff2 = Mid(ff, i, Len(find_text))
                                    
                                  If ff2 = find_text Then
                                    count_result = count_result + 1                                  
                                      MsgBox "Number result: " & count_result & vbNewLine & Mid(ff, i - 150, i + 200), vbOKCancel + vbMsgBoxRight + vbAbortRetryIgnore, Filename
                                  End If
                                    DoEvents
                             Next
b:
                  End If                   
                 sheet1.Close
                 file = Dir
                 DoEvents
              Wend
book1.Quit
MsgBox " end!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of just telling us what you're doing, you should tell us also what you're trying to achieve. FWIW. Word paragraphs don't have line breaks unless one has been inserted intentionally.

Comment: IIf I search for a few words in multiple files in Word (works of many years and topics. For example if you search for the word "carrot", it can appear in natural medicine, alternative medicine, risks, carrot cultivation, marketing and different varieties....).
The reason I am interested in receiving
new line character  It is for identifying titles In the meantime I used Ole Sjogren's idea and it gives a partial answer because it requires matching the title to the search scan of the requested word/words. But it's also something.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but the following will store the contents of the document in a string array by splitting on the `vbCr`-constant representing the line break:

```
Dim sLinesArr() As String
sLinesArr = Split(sheet1.Content.Text, vbCr)
```

The array can then be used in a loop:

```
Dim vLine As Variant

For Each vLine In sLinesArr
    MsgBox vLine
Next
```